# how do I use this OnCompleted function?

Tags: flutter, dart

This library I found that handles music playing has the following variable public.

```
void Function() onCompleted;
```

I want to change the icon of a button when the track is finished, so that it returns to a play icon.

I tried using `musicPlayer.OnCompleted(() { **stuff** });` but that gives me a syntax error `Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.`

How do I subscribe on that event, or how do I check if OnCompleted has been called?

I am still pretty new to dart but can't wrap my head around this one. I tried subscribing like in Angular or looking up if there's a different syntax for it, but I am at a loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you have to set `onCompleted` to something, specifically a function taking no parameters and returning void.

It would be normal to provide something like this in the constructor. Is there a named, optional parameter for this? Alternatively, there may be a setter.

Let's assume there's a setter. You could write:

```
  musicPlayer.onCompleted = (){/* do stuff*/};
```

Comment: awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks so much!